# Create Images from existing image and display them in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, image

I have an Image like

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
```

(Actually its a Webcam-Stream shown in a PictureBox)

And from this I want to "extract" single Rectangles (the coordinates are given) and want to display those parts in a seperated PictureBox but at the moment I have a mental block.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Winform? Wpf? Asp.Net?

Comment: @Christoph Do you want to select a region of the image and display that region in another PictureBox ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using EmguCV and I haven't tested these things..But this may give you some lead.

- Instead of using **PictureBox** use **ImageBox** provided with EmguCV.So there won't be any need for image conversion.
- If you want to convert the image,From EmguCV documentation `The Image class has a ToBitmap() function that return a Bitmap object, which can easily be displayed on a PictureBox control using Windows Form`
- Now you will have a bitmap,If you want to select a particular region from this bitmap,then the followings links will help you.

  [crop an image using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734930/how-to-crop-an-image-using-c)

  [How to cut a part of image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484935/how-to-cut-a-part-of-image-in-c-sharp)